# Reuse data from $http in factory

Tags: angularjs

I understand that the appropriate method to share data between controllers in Angular.js is by using Factories or Services.

```
app.controller('Controller1', function($scope, DataService) {
  DataService.getValues().then(
    function(results) {
      // on success
      console.log('getValues onsuccess');
    });
});

app.controller('Controller2', function($scope, DataService) {
  DataService.getValues().then(
    function(results) {
      // on success
      console.log('getValues onsuccess');
    });
});

app.factory('DataService', function($http) {
  var getValues = function() {
    console.log('making http request');
    return $http.get("/api/getValues");
  };

  return {
    getValues: getValues
  }
});
```

I have two controllers calling the same method in a factory twice
and this is perfectly fine and everything is working as it should. My only concer is that it seems a bit unecessary to make the same request twice? 
Would the use of $broadcast be a better approach? 

Or could i structure my code differenty so that the service is called only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the results of the request in the factory and retrieve those instead.

```
app.factory('DataService', function($http) {
  var values;
  var requestValues = function() {
    console.log('making http request');
    $http.get("/api/getValues").then(
        function(results){
            values = results;
        });
  };
  var getValues = function() {
    return values;
  };
  return {
    requestValues : requestValues,
    getValues: getValues
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So I would have to first call `requestValues`and then `getValues` from the controller?

Comment: Exactly. You might also want to add a callback to requestValues() so your controller knows when the data is ready. This approach gives your controllers control over when you 're-retrieve' the requested data. If this is not something you need I suggest going with navigator's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is somekind of static and may not change very often over time you could do something like:

```
app.factory('DataService', function($http) {
  self = this;
  this.isLoaded = false;
  this.results;

  this.getValues = function() {
    console.log('making http request');
    $http.get("/api/getValues").then(
      function(results) {
        // on success
        console.log('getValues onsuccess');
        self.isLoaded = true
        this.results = results;
        return results;
      })
    );
  };
})
```

And in the controller:

```
app.controller('Controller2', function($scope, DataService) {
  if(!DataService.isLoaded){
    results = DataService.getValues()
  }else{
    results = DataService.results;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should consider caching in your DataService. Add a variable to hold the result from the http service and a time-stamp variable to store the time it was retrieved.

If a second call to the service is within a preset time period (lets say, 5 seconds), then http call is not made and data from the cache is returned.

```
app.factory('DataService', function($http) {
    var cachedValue = null;
    var lastGet = null;
    var getValues = function() {
        var timeNow = new Date();
        if (cachedValue == null || ((timeNow - lastGet) < 5000)) {
            console.log('making http request');
            lastGet = timeNow;
            cachedValue = $http.get("/api/getValues");
        } else console.log('returning cached value');
        return cachedValue;
    };

    return {
        getValues: getValues
    }
});
```