# filling data from one html to another html file

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, rest

I am getting few records from database (from a REST call). I have a separate page to update record. On the display-all-recs page, once I click on the recId, I want to open that data into update page.

I am using angular in the front end. Do I have to make more GET call? (I don't want to do it as I already have the data displayed in the table)

Is there any way that I can fill up this update page with existing values statically?

Comment: Do you have two separeted controllers or you use the same controller for both views? If you use the same controller, you can use a scope variable to store your data and when you open the view edit, you just need to load the data from the scope variable. If you use two different controllers, you can put them in the same file and use an external variable and use it in the two controllers so when one change the other change too. Another way is using a service that store your data in your browser so you can access it wherever you want.

Comment: I think the best way is do a getFull to load the basics infos for all reccords and then use a get to load all the infos of a specific reccord. This way you will save bandwith not loading data that you wont use.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33822223/reuse-data-from-http-in-factory